# Is it real to implement IdentityServer with pkce flow using WebApi interface

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I have project with Angular-WebApi architecture, I need to add IS to authorize users, but I don't need mvc with redirect, I would like to send user creds from Angular App to IS API, get JWT, and use this JWT, to get data from Resource API. I can't find any examples of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-auth-oidc-client for your angular app
you can refer here for sample how to do it - https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client

for Idp sample, Identityserver4 did provide sample for configuration under JavaScriptClient project. You can refer here, https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/4_JavaScriptClient

You can also refer to my project which use angular, IS4 and resource server
https://github.com/firdausng/testnt

Answer (score -1):

> but I don't need mvc with redirect, I would like to send user creds from Angular App to IS API, get JWT, and use this JWT, to get data from Resource API.

Normally user will be redirect to Identity Server and enter credential in login page , in Angular application , you can use Authorization Code Flow with PKCE .

But if you want to collect user's credential in Angular and send credential to IDS , you can use the [Resource Owner Password Flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore1/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html)  with Identity Server . But that is **not recommended** because The ROPC flow requires a high degree of trust and user exposure and you should only use this flow when other, more secure, flows can't be used.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: off-topic because of `I can't find any examples of it.` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." I would expect a user with 15k rep to know these rules.

Comment: @IanKemp The question is not about finding examples (as there are none) but rather about why there are no examples available. In this case I don't think this question is off-topic.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic, I would like to know is it real to implement PKCE flow without redirecting user

Comment: @ДенисРедько , Code flow + PKCE  needs  redirecting user to identity provider , that is by design and for security reasons .